# Error when trying to require browser version of NeDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify, nedb

I'm developing a client side application and I want to use the browser version of NeDB.
Using gulp, I run browserify to create my `bundle.js`. The problem is when I try to import the browser version of NeDB I face an error about a require inside the `nedb.js` file.

Here is the require:

```
var Nedb = require('nedb/browser-version/out/nedb')
```

The error:

```
events.js:141
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './model' from 'E:\Rafael\Dev\situations\node_modules\nedb\browser-version\out'
```

Looking for model inside the nedb.js file, I saw that it tries to import using the current directory, but the file is in another one.

The require used by NeDB:

```
var model = require('./model')
```

File structure:

```
nedb
  browser-version
    out
      nedb.js
  lib
    model.js
```

What am I missing about the NeDB browser version and browserify?

I'm already using browserify with success. I'm able to require modules like angular and foundation. The problem starts when I try to include NeDB.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to `nedb.min.js` might work, this once let me pass `browserify` :

```
var Nedb = require('nedb/browser-version/out/nedb.min.js')
```